# How to present a CardView when FAB is touched

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have a fragment that gets a list of students vocabulary words from my server using Volley. The list of words is displayed in a RecyclerView with a FAB on top. How can I wire up my FAB so that when it is pressed a CardView will be displayed like a pop up over the RecylerView. The purpose of this is to use that CardView as a form to communicate with another script that will allow the user to enter a word to add to the list. When the button is clicked on the CardView it should run the POST script and disappear. Is this doable inside a single fragment?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_ui, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    wordRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.wordsRecyclerView);
    wordRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    wordRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE));
    mWordAdapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity());
    wordRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWordAdapter);
    TextView clientTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientText);
    Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    final String username = args.getString("USER_NAME");
    clientTextView.setText("Word List For: " + username);

    FloatingActionButton wordButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.wordFloatingButton);
    wordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    sendRequest();
    return view;
  }


 private void sendRequest() {

    Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    final String username = args.getString("USER_NAME");
    final String URL = JSON_URL + username;
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mWordArrayList = parseJSONResponse(response);
            mWordAdapter.setWordArrayList(mWordArrayList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}


public ArrayList<Word> parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {
    ArrayList<Word> mWordArrayList = new ArrayList<Word>();
    if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {

    }
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject usersWords = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String words = usersWords.getString(KEY_WORD);
            String addbys = usersWords.getString(KEY_ADDBY);
            Word word = new Word(words, addbys);
            word.setWord(words);
            word.setAddby("Added by: " + addbys);
            mWordArrayList.add(word);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mWordArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a temporary solution. I would be interested to see if someone can implement the above or tell me a better way to do this.

What I ended up doing is just creating a new Activity AddWord.class and calling that from the onClickListener. Then I create a view and a custom Theme like this...

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

When the FAB is clicked the view pops up on top of the RecyclerView which is still visible behind. The user can complete the form and add the word to the list and then return the RecyclerView.

Not sure how expensive this is, so if anyone has a better alternative let me know!